# avr gcc прерывания, глобальная переменная

Tags: c, avr-gcc

Заметил такую интересную особенность, в прерываниях глобальные переменные изменяются, но эти изменения недоступны для main
допустим есть программа частотомер

```
#define F_CPU 3686400LU
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "LCD.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
char buffer[10];
unsigned long c=0;
void eraseBuf(char *buf){
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        buf[i]=0;
    }
}
void initt0(void){
    TCCR0|=1<<CS00|1<<CS01|1<<CS02;//внешний источник тактирования
    TIMSK|=1<<TOIE0;
    TCNT0=0;
}
void initPWM(void){
    DDRD|=1<<7;//oc2
    OCR2=170; 
    TCCR2|=(1<<WGM20)|(1<<WGM21)|(1<<COM21)|(0<<CS22)|(1<<CS21)|(0<<CS20);
    //fastPWM; 1/64
    TCNT2=0;
}
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){
    c=c+1;
}
int main(){
    initPWM();
    LCDinit();
    LCDclear();
    initt0();
    sei();
    while(1){ 
        _delay_ms(1000);
        LCDclear();
        c=c*256+TCNT0;
        LCDstring(itoa(c,buffer,10),0,0);
        eraseBuf(buffer);
        TCNT0=0;
        c=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

на дисплей будет выведен бред, который остался в TCNT0, без оптимизации кода глобальная переменная доступна, но программа работает неадекватно.

Comment: А собственно вопрос Ваш в чём?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте ключевое слово `volatile` к определению.

```
volatile unsigned long c=0;
```

Это даст знать компилятору не оптимизировать переменную `c`. Она используется в цикле в `main` и с вероятность 100% загружается в регистры один раз перед циклом, а не перечитывается из памяти. С `volatile` компилятор всегда будет выполнять загрузку значения из памяти в регистр при каждом обращении к этой переменной.

Comment: спасибо! помогло!